# Android | Dialog with Binding Ignores Some Parametres

Tags: java, android

Why does Dialog created with Binding ignores `android:layout_height` and `layout_marginHorizontal`? I guess it ignores something more, but thats what I have problems with.

**Dialog Layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="12dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialogTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_outline_28dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
Dialog defaultDialog = new Dialog(this);
defaultDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_test);
defaultDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.dialog_background));
defaultDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
defaultDialog.setCancelable(true);

Dialog dialogWithBinding = new Dialog(this);
DialogTestBinding dialogTestBinding = DialogTestBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
dialogWithBinding.setContentView(dialogTestBinding.getRoot());
dialogWithBinding.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.dialog_background));
    dialogWithBinding.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
dialogWithBinding.setCancelable(true);

findViewById(R.id.showDefaultDialog).setOnClickListener(view -> {
    TextView dialogTV = defaultDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogTV);
    dialogTV.setText("Dialog");
    defaultDialog.show();
});
findViewById(R.id.showBindingDialog).setOnClickListener(view -> {
    dialogTestBinding.dialogTV.setText("Dialog with Binding");
    dialogWithBinding.show();
});
```

`dialog_background` is simple transparent shape

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you added this line:

```
dialogWithBinding.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

The logic behind it is this line:

```
defaultDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_test);
```

sets the **window** content view. And when you call setLayout it changes the layout_width and layout_height and overrides the values you put in the xml:

```
    public void setLayout(int width, int height) {
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getAttributes();
        attrs.width = width;
        attrs.height = height;
        dispatchWindowAttributesChanged(attrs);
    }
```

So my suggestion is to remove the setLayout line of code.